# node.js module export how to use data among all modules?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I would like to use updated (and only then) globals among all node modules. How to do that? Questions are in code.

**app.js**

```
var data = 'data';

var global = require('glob.js')(data);
// here we are require your globals variables and we corectly 'set them'

console.log(globals.glob1);
// we can use them here
```

**glob.js**

```
module.exports  = function(data)
{
    var globs = {
        glob1 : data.toLowerCase(),
        glob2 : data.toUpperCase()
    }
    return globs;
}
```

**mod.js**

```
var global = require('glob.js'); // I require globals but they are not set...

function funct(someOtherData, someMoreData)
{
    var test = global.glob1;
    console.log(test);
    // why I can't use globals here ? How can I use corectly set globals (globals need to be updated first - app.js, then ALL other modules should be able to use correctly set globals)?
}

module.export = funct;
```

Comment: `var global` stores only the result of function from `glob.js`, in the app.js scope, so that isn't actually global variable.

Comment: Yea cause I need to set globals variables first - I do this by require the glob.js module with global variables object and pass there data - there are 'updated'. Then they should be shared among all node.js modules. What Am I missing here?

Comment: wait, here: `console.log(globals.glob1);` you use `globals` not `global`.

Comment: thanks, but I still can't share (updated) globals among other modules (I do require glob.js inside them but the data is not correctly set).

Comment: `var global = require('glob.js');` in *mod.js*, you can't expect it to have global variables, since it requires it as **new** module.

Comment: right, it load immediately glob.js and data there is not set yet by app.js so all globals are useless. I can always pass them by function from app.js but I thought there is a way to share updated globals among all the modules... not as a GLOBALS (global.globals) but as a module required by all modules. I hope you get me. If not I try to explain this more, and pass new updated example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the answer scroll down to the **TLDR** section below but do read on to understand why.

## Part1 - the difference between a function and a function call

Your first mistake is that you are exporting a function, not an object:

```
module.exports  = function(data) // <---- this is a function
{
    var globs = {
        glob1 : data.toLowerCase(),
        glob2 : data.toUpperCase()
    }
    return globs;
}
```

and in ***app.js*** you do this:

```
console.log(globs.glob1); <--- globs is a function, not an object
```

when you should be doing this:

```
console.log(globs().glob1);
```

Why is this? OK, lets forget for a moment your module. Consider the following code:

```
var a = function(){ return 2 };

console.log(a);   // do you expect this to print a function or 2?
console.log(a()); // what do you expect this to print?
```

This is a very basic rule about functions in all programming languages, not just javascript: to get the return value you need to call the function. So in your code:

```
function myExportedFunction (data) {
    // some logic here...
    return globs;
}

console.log(myExportedFunction);         // prints a function
console.log(myExportedFunction());       // prints the globs object
console.log(myExportedFunction().glob1); // prints value of glob1
```

So it's simple really. There is no magic syntax going on. You've just forgotten to return the glob object and are using the function pointer instead. Obviously the function has no `glob1` property so it's correct for it to be undefined.

## Part2 - function local variables

OK. So let's say you made the changes I recommended above. There's an obvious problem with the way the function was written. What happens when you do this:

```
var glob = require('glob.js')();
console.log(glob.glob1); // <--- prints "undefined"
```

So the first problem is you're not checking if you're passing data or nothing. So every time you call the function you will overwrite the stored value.

There's another problem, you are always returning a different object every time you call the function. Let's look at how local variables work when returned:

```
function a () {
    var data = {}
    return data;
}

var x = a();
var y = a();

x.testing = 1;
y.testing = 2;

console.log(x.testing); // prints 1
console.log(y.testing); // prints 2
```

So, every time you call a function that creates a local variable you are returning a different object. Actually what's doing this is not really the variable but the object literal syntax:

```
var a = {};
// is basically the same as
var a = new Object();
```

If we change the above example to:

```
function a () {
    return {};
}
```

it would still behave the same.

## TLDR

So, how do we fix it? Simple, create the object outside of the function and check if we pass `data` to initialize:

```
var globs = {
    glob1 : "",
    glob2 : ""
}

module.exports  = function(data)
{
    globs.glob1 = data.toLowerCase();
    globs.glob2 = data.toUpperCase();

    return globs;
}
```

Now everything should work:

In **app.js**

```
var global = require('glob.js')(data);
```

In **mod.js**

```
var global = require('glob.js')();
```

---

#### Epologue - modules are singletons

It may or may not be obvious to you why the above should work. In case you already know why I'm writing this as reference to future readers.

In node.js modules are implemented as proper singletons. Therefore in node if you want a singleton all you need to do is write a module, you don't need to implement any special code for it.

What this means is that all module globals (module scoped variables) are shared amongst all requires. Here's a very simple module to share one variable amongst all modules:

**shared.js**

```
var x = "";

module.exports = {
    set: function (val) {x=val},
    get: function () {return x}
}
```

**a.js**

```
var shared = require('./shared');

shared.set("hello world");
```

**b.js**

```
var shared = require('./shared');

console.log(shared.get()); // prints "hello world"
```

We're using this feature to declare a shared `glob` variable in the code above.

Comment: Wow,excelent answer.I did use var global=require('glob.js')(data); in app.js and console.log(globals.glob1);so as I understand global is our required function (that return object) and a data is our parameter.Return was used,so it bring back the global (glob)object.Very nice described with excellent simple examples!It's good to actually be SURE that what I'm think is correct :)So by putting the global object out of the function (in glob.js),we can update it by app.js and just read it by our modules(mod.js).But the problem is that object contains .toLowerCase() and methods do not work so is this

Comment: The object does not contain `.toLowerCase()`.. at least not the way you've written it. All you did is assign the return value of `.toLowerCase()` (which is a string) to `glob1` and `glob2`. All the object contains are strings. I can easily change my example to do that

Comment: Done. It now assigns lowercase strings to the properties

Comment: Yea to be understood by this I refereed to THIS keyword not this example. The thing is that var glob={glob1 : some.trim(), glob2 : some.length} does not posses simple string |''|, and using a method, or then there, is hard, (and you need to use otherr name conwention then global.yuorneededvalue - and that is another -) and if var global = require('glob.js')(); is used in module it brings reference errors. If you put everything to function, then it cannot update glob object, cause it simply does not have data to update key:value pairs (var global = require('glob.js')(); - no parameter here).

Comment: var global = require('glob.js')(); and you don't want to add parameter here (other then before) in you modules, cause it will overwrite the variables.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. What exactly are you trying to do? Because my examples above does exactly what you specified in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. Use nodejs [global](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) variable (not recommended)
2. Create shared module

You chose 2nd option, but did it a bit wrong way by exporting a function. When you import the package and call the function it always creates new **globs** object and fulfill it with your *data*. Instead you can export an object. Simple example

***glob.js***
Global object is defined here

```
module.exports = {
  glob1: '1',
  glob2: '2'
};
```

***mod.js***
You can change global object here, like

```
var globs = require('./glob');

module.exports.updateGlob1 = function(data) {
  globs.glob1 = data;
};
```

***app.js***
Here if you access global variable you can see it updated

```
var globs = require('./glob');
var mod = require('./mod');

mod.updateGlob1('1 plus 2');
console.log(globs.glob1); // Output: '1 plus 2'
```

There can be more complex examples, as for module design pattern often IIFE is used.

**UPDATE**

Another example using IIFE.

***glob.js***

```
module.exports = (function() {
  var glob1 = 'initial value';

  return {
    // Getter method
    getGlob1() {
      return glob1;
    },

    // Setter method
    setGlob1(value) {
      glob1 = value;
    }
  }
})();
```

***mod.js***

```
var shared = require('./shared');

module.exports.testFn = function() {
  // Access global variable with getter method
  console.log('In mod.js', shared.getGlob1());
};
```

***app.js***

```
var shared = require('./shared');
var mod = require('./mod');

// Print initial value
console.log('Initial', shared.getGlob1());

// Set new value to global variable
shared.setGlob1('new value');

// Print updated value
console.log('In app.js', shared.getGlob1());

// Use global variable in mod.js file
mod.testFn();
```

Comment: It does not work as expected. I have globs object in glob.js - but they need to be updated to work correctly. Then and only then I would like to use them in all modules (share them). So app.js is updating the glob.js, and then all other modules - mod.js is using the globals in some easy way like globs.myGlobalObjectVariable1, globmyGlobalObjectVariable2 etc. I tried sugested IIFE to no avail, but maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check the example with IIFE implementation, I have also added comments for you, hope it's more clear now. Play around and try to do it the way you need it. Ask me if anything...

Comment: You don't need IIFE. A module in node is implemented as an IIFE. Just put the variable outside `module.exports` and it will be shared

Comment: @slebetman right, I just wanted to show how module pattern implemented, there is example with exporting object which is shared in nodejs environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `global.` variable identifier to set global variables in NodeJS, instead of `var`, example:

**app.js**

```
var data = 'data';

var glob = require('./glob.js');
glob(data);
// here we are require your globals variables and we corectly 'set them'

console.log(global.gl.glob1);
var mod = require('./mod.js');
mod();
// we can use them here
```

**glob.js**

```
module.exports  = function(data)
{
    console.log("setting globals");
    global.gl = {
        glob1 : '1' + data,
        glob2 : '2' + data
    }
    // return global.gl; // can be removed 
}
```

**mod.js**

```
function funct(someOtherData, someMoreData)
{
    var test = global.gl.glob1;
    console.log(test);
    test = global.gl.glob2;
    console.log(test);
    // why I can't use globals here ? How can I use corectly set globals (globals need to be updated first - app.js, then ALL other modules should be able to use correctly set globals)?
}

module.exports = funct;
```

As you can see in **glob.js**, i switched to `var globs =` to `global.gl =` and then in **mod.js** used it as `global.gl`.

Running **app.js** outputs:

```
setting globals
1data // From app.js
1data // From mod.js imported in app.js
2data // From mod.js imported in app.js
```

Comment: Yes this is working. However the whole point is to not use globals, right (so .global instead of var is not really a solution...)? Otherwise I just could use var glob1 = '';, var glob2 = ''; in app.js and just updated them. I like this approach but Imust get rid of globals (well maybe most of them :). AHhh and you can use just gl.glob1 instead of global.gl.glob1

Comment: but you can still add on top of the mod.js initialization of *local variables* from *global*, e.g. `var gl = global.gl;` and add the function that updates them on each call to every function of *mod.js*.